# jQuery UI Modal Dialog cause webpage has exired error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

I am getting a `"webpage had expired"` error in IE9 only. I'm calling a modal dialog with 2 submit buttons (image buttons). When I click on them
I can see the the pop up and then I get the "webpage had expired" message.

**My function:**

```
moreSubscribersQuestions: function () {
        var dlg=  $("#dialogMoreClients").dialog({
            modal: true,
            //dialogClass: 'WsErrorMessage'
            dialogClass: 'addMoreClientPopUp',
            width: 500,
            height:400
        });
        $('.ui-helper-clearfix:after').removeClass();
        //$('div.FinishPurchasePopUpBTn').each(function () {
        //    this.addClass('FinishPurchasePopUpBTn');
        //});
        dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
    }
```

After removing  `dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));` the problem does not occur any more. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your .aspx code? What are you trying to achieve with the dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first")); line?

Comment: with dlg.dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first")); I can use the button as asp:imagebutton (event) .

Comment: without more code it's hard to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This post [The Most Likely Cause of "Webpage Has Expired"](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/likely-cause-webpage-expired-27135.html) by Fraser Sherman describes some reasons why you might see that error in IE. Here are some additional thoughts from a [forum post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1813697.aspx/1) I read.

Without knowing exactly what you are doing it sounds like you may have performed a POST (possibly with ASP.NET) and then tried to redirect the user to a page in their browser's history.

Options to resolve the issue may be to...

1. Find another way to redirect the user other than `window.history.go` or similar technique (preferable)
2. Make sure the page isn't cachable (could affect performance)
3. Kick the page into compatibility mode (last resort)

It would be helpful to see the code inside of your dialog. That may give more insight into what is going on.

Comment: After the popup appeared , nothing suppose to happened until the user answer the  question on the popup.
and the button function is on the code  behind of the same page...no redirection to another page.

Different thought is can that line can trigger security problem as this problem happened only on Production level

Comment: @Rob here I calling js from code behind
do you need the click events 2 ?
                if (_lead.isAsked == false && _lead.Subscribers.Count < _lead.MaxSubscribers)
                {
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "moreSubscribersQuestions", "eWave.PurchaseFormStage3.moreSubscribersQuestions();", true);

                }
                else
                {
                    finishPurchase();
                    
                }
                
             }